# Webcam not working on Sony Vaio with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, webcam, vaio

I'm new to ubuntu, literally installed it yesterday, but enjoying it so far!

Except for this issue with the webcam, which is not working at all. I've been through the questions and answers here, and elsewhere, to no avail.

The webcam appears to be showing with lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ca:1830 Ricoh Co., Ltd Visual Communication Camera VGP-VCC2 [R5U870]
```

The kernel version is: **3.11.0-19-generic**

I've tried installing the r5u87x but that hasn't worked - I'm pretty sure I need the **r5u870**.

So I tried that [here](http://download.tuxfamily.org/arakhne/pool/universe/r/ricoh-webcam-r5u870/) but I get this fatal error:

```
linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory

nopalita@picante:~/r5u870$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build M=/home/nopalita/r5u870 V=0 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic'
CC [M]  /home/nopalita/r5u870/r5u870.o
In file included from /home/nopalita/r5u870/r5u870.c:60:0:
/home/nopalita/r5u870/usbcam/usbcam.h:38:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/nopalita/r5u870/r5u870.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/nopalita/r5u870] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And after a fresh install of 12.04, and following the instructions the comments below (which seemed to install ok), using "sudo modprobe r5u870" I now get an error saying that the module cannot be found? FATAL: Module r5u870 not found. http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7234919/

I'm now completely out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to build the firmware from source as there are debian packages available in http://download.tuxfamily.org/arakhne/pool/universe/r/ricoh-webcam-r5u870/ for both 32 and 64bits:

Depending on your architecture, try to download:

```
ricoh-webcam-r5u870-firmware_0.11.6-0arakhne0_i386.deb
```

or for 64bits:

```
ricoh-webcam-r5u870-firmware_0.11.6-0arakhne0_amd64.deb
```

Finally open a terminal, go to the folder where you downloaded the firmware package an type (assuming you're running the 64bits release):

```
sudo dpkg -i ricoh-webcam-r5u870-firmware_0.11.6-0arakhne0_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks @Sylvain - I downloaded and installed the i386 debian packages, but I'm still having problems. A few errors showed up during the installs, and then when I check at the end with modprobe r5u870 I get: FATAL: Module r5u870 not found. The r5u870 files seem to be present in /lib/firmware

Comment: Please add them to http://pastebin.ubuntu.com and put the link in your question

Comment: Thanks @Sylvain - link is here http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7234919/

Comment: I installed the .deb file, then what do I do? My computer still can't find the webcam.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the following already packaged sources:

**Google Code** - https://code.google.com/p/r5u870/ (Webcams like HP/Ricoh Webcam 1000, etc)

**Launchpad** - https://launchpad.net/~nbdarvin/+archive/ricoh-webcam-r5u870

Or as mentioned in the [Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744189) try the:

- http://download.tuxfamily.org/arakhne/pool/universe/r/ricoh-webcam-r5u870/ricoh-webcam-r5u870-firmware_0.11.6-0arakhne0_i386.deb
- http://ricoh-webcam-r5u870_0.11.6-0arakhne0_i386.deb/

Answer (score 0):

Grab my latest version from here... works for the WDM drivers:
http://modelrail.otenko.com/vaio-ux/r5u870-for-v4l2-linux-kernel-3-13

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this answer with more information about how to use that.